# Xcode displays same content for ALL NSString when debugging

Tags: xcode, debugging

[Please see my screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyMb8.png)

As you can see, my Xcode always display a strange string "http://itunes...." for all NSString objects, but they are different in fact.

All I know is I did use this string (http://itunes....) in one of my project several months (or years) ago, but I really don't know why it still here??

I have tried to update Xcode version、clean cache、restart Xcode and Mac, but do not help at all. Anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: Your screenshot link is not working

Comment: oops. I think it works now @RajatJain